# Inner html not using my linked stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, innerhtml

I'm trying to make a script that inserts my header and footer into all of my pages, but the inserted html doesn't use my linked stylesheet. I found this out when I tried to make specific style requests to my images that I have.

I have looked all over google, but nothing has worked. I tried injecting a style, but that didn't do anything (it made the footer disappear).

```js
function footer(isHome) {
  let footer = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
  let html = `<p>JoJo Studios 2019</p>
    <div class="links">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUwHObXqdY0OC3c3gNDkKFw"><img id="youtube" class="footer-link" src="${isHome ? `` : `../`}images/youtube-logo.png" alt="YouTube"></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/jojo/?hl=en"><img id="insta" class="footer-link" src="${isHome ? `` : `../`}images/instagram-logo.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
    </div>`;
  footer.innerHTML = html;
  console.log(html);
}



function display(page) {
  header(page);
  let isHome = page == "home";
  footer(isHome);
}

footer(true);
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.footer-link {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-link:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 221, 153);
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```

It should change the color on the hover, but nothing happens.

Comment: I see it's working fine

Comment: Use DOM methods like `.appendChild`.

Comment: how would I use appendChild with my footer? @AlexKudryashev

Comment: while setting `innerHTML`, appendChild is not necessary.

Comment: i saw that innerHtml doesn't always use stylesheet somewhere. I'm confused about that. @Towkir

Comment: Your code is working fine.
Let me create a snippet by editing your post, since there is nothing wrong, i can't post an answer.

Comment: What color? You’re putting the class on images, not on text. What color is supposed to change?

Comment: my edit has been approved, now check the snippet, is it what you expected ? I changed the body background color only, to make the white links visible. note that the images won't be loaded here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOM methods `.createElement` and `.appendChild` instead of `.innerHTML = html_block`. Something like this.

```
function footer(isHome) {
    const footer = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
    let el = document.createElement('p');
    el.innerHTML = 'oJo Studios 2019';
    footer.appendChild(el);
    el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'links';
    let anchor = documeent.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUwHObXqdY0OC3c3gNDkKFw';
    //other attributes
    el.appendChild(anchor);
    footer.appendChild(el);
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: I see that the css has started to work. Thank you! However, my png images still don't change color and as I was looking online for changing image color something about filters came up. Do you perhaps know if filters are the way to change a png image's color? @AlexKudryashev